noVNC takes long time to connect to x11vnc in docker
I have x11vnc running inside a docker container with alpine as base image. (5900 is exposed and mapped to hosts 5900) I use Xvfb as well. I run x11vnc inside the container using this command
x11vnc -display :0 -forever -nopw -listen 0.0.0.0 -xkb

I can connect to ths normally using a normal vnc client like realvnc without any issue and any unusual delay. This is the output when real vnc is used
24/09/2024 15:42:00 Got connection from client 112.134.157.141
24/09/2024 15:42:00   0 other clients
24/09/2024 15:42:00 Normal socket connection
24/09/2024 15:42:00 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
24/09/2024 15:42:00   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
24/09/2024 15:42:00 incr accepted_client=2 for 112.134.157.141:48624  sock=10
24/09/2024 15:42:01 Client Protocol Version 3.8
24/09/2024 15:42:01 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
24/09/2024 15:42:01 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 1
24/09/2024 15:42:01 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: returning securityResult for client rfb version >= 3.8
24/09/2024 15:42:01 created   xdamage object: 0xc00026
24/09/2024 15:42:03 client_set_net: 112.134.157.141  0.0016
24/09/2024 15:42:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000018)
24/09/2024 15:42:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000016)
24/09/2024 15:42:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x00000015)
24/09/2024 15:42:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000F)
24/09/2024 15:42:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFFFEC6)
24/09/2024 15:42:03 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 112.134.157.141
24/09/2024 15:42:03 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 112.134.157.141
24/09/2024 15:42:03 Using ZRLE encoding for client 112.134.157.141
24/09/2024 15:42:03 Pixel format for client 112.134.157.141:
24/09/2024 15:42:03   8 bpp, depth 6
24/09/2024 15:42:03   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 

'
But when i try to connect it through react-vnc (which uses noVNC) It takes a long time to connect
This is the output from x11vnc when attempting to connect with react-vnc, it get stuck at "created xdamage object: 0xc00027" for about 4 mins.

24/09/2024 15:42:43 Got connection from client 112.134.157.141
24/09/2024 15:42:43   0 other clients
24/09/2024 15:42:43 Got 'ws' WebSockets handshake
24/09/2024 15:42:43   - webSocketsHandshake: using binary/raw encoding
24/09/2024 15:42:43   - WebSockets client version hybi-13
24/09/2024 15:42:43 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
24/09/2024 15:42:43   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
24/09/2024 15:42:43 incr accepted_client=3 for 112.134.157.141:47494  sock=10
24/09/2024 15:42:43 created   xdamage object: 0xc00027
24/09/2024 15:46:42 hybiReadHeader: read; Connection reset by peer
24/09/2024 15:46:42 rfbProcessClientProtocolVersion: read: Connection reset by peer
24/09/2024 15:46:42 client_count: 0
24/09/2024 15:46:42 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
24/09/2024 15:46:42 Client 112.134.157.141 gone
24/09/2024 15:46:42 Statistics             events    Transmit/ RawEquiv ( saved)
24/09/2024 15:46:42  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
24/09/2024 15:46:42 Statistics             events    Received/ RawEquiv ( saved)
24/09/2024 15:46:42  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
24/09/2024 15:46:45 destroyed xdamage object: 0xc00027

'
it get stuck at "created xdamage object: 0xc00027" for about 4 mins. And starts working after "connection reset by peer"
This is what the next.js implementation looks like.

"use client";

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { VncScreen } from 'react-vnc';

function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <VncScreen
      url='ws://<vps_ip>:5900/'
      scaleViewport
      background="#000000"
      style={{
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
      }}
      ref={ref}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
in chrome i also get this warning
"index.es.js:9621 WebSocket connection to 'ws://<vps_ip>:5900/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
close   @   index.es.js:9621
"

Is this normal, if not how to fix

so you are executing this VNC client in a web browser?

@FrankThomas yes

so I generally equate "connection reset by peer" in a browser as an issue with HTTPS and firewalls. it is weird however that you are seeing that message in the server log instead of the clients.

do your browser dev tools show anything amiss in terms of network flow (requeset/response) like specific HTTP errors or timeouts? anything relevant in the javascript console?

@FrankThomas after a while (before anything shows up) I see a bunch of GET requests to ws://, with status code 101 switching protocols with among others these headers "sec-websocket-extensions:
permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
sec-websocket-key:
BHrgc920jxn5EIw+0jjxeA==
sec-websocket-version:
13
upgrade:
websocket"
